# Javascript plugin to manage placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the Twitter sign up page at https://twitter.com/signup

Even when you click on first input field "Full name" placeholder stays there until I start typing something. That is awesome.

Does anyone know of a good jQuery plugin that comes close to that?

Comment: its called watermarking.

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/watermark

Comment: Twitter does it with an overlay div that is hidden as soon as you type something into the text box.

Comment: But it is not standard watermarking. The placeholder stays even if you have clicked on the input box.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of plugins out there for this.  This is my homegrown solution I use:

```
/**
 *  Yet another textbox hint plugin...
 *  Usage: $('.selector').hint();
 *  The title attribute of the input will be used as the watermark value.
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.hint = function() {
        var hintedClass = 'hinted';
        return this.each(function() {
            var $field = $(this),
                title = $field.attr('title'),
                $form = $(this.form);

            // bail out if there isn't a title attribute
            if (!title) { return; }

            // add/remove hint behavior
            var addHint = function() {
                    $field.val() || $field.addClass(hintedClass).val(title);
                },
                removeHint = function() {
                    if ($field.hasClass(hintedClass) && $field.val() === title) {
                        $field.val('').removeClass(hintedClass);
                    }
                };

            // set our focus/blur handlers
            $field.focus(removeHint).blur(addHint);

            // if the field isn't already focused, add the hint now
            $field.is(':focus') || addHint();

            // form submission handling
            $form.submit(removeHint);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Note that a "proper" plugin would probably provide some options for stuff like the hinted class, and how to determine the watermark value - this is just something I whipped together recently and hadn't planned on necessarily sharing (but it works).

Answer (score 0):

Zero JavaScript needed in browsers that support the [HTML5 placeholder attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

```
<label>Description: <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="My Email Account"></label>
```

Comment: with a standard placeholder when you click on it the placeholder disappears. that is not the case with the twitter sign up.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this example](http://mrcoles.com/blog/persistent-placeholders-tutorial-focus/) that functions just like the twitter one, but you might want to grab some additional CSS from the twitter bootstrap CSS if you want the exact styling.

I talk more about the method in this similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630540/jquery-placeholder-that-shows-the-placeholder-until-text-is-typed/8127353#8127353).