# How to make the input have text in it while on focus?

Tags: javascript, css, html, input

Please check the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/cT9kg/4/

As you can see its a search field with a button.

**If you have trouble understanding what I mean below please just look at the "Title" input on the Ask a question page.**

The input has autofocus on.

**BUT**

How can I have it so text is already in the input with autofocus on but as soon as someone types into the input the text disappears.

**AND**

When someone has entered text in the input but then deletes it, it goes back to the way it was at the beginning: on focus with text in it instructing the person what to type in the input.

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0):

You could define the default value.

On focus - empty value, if the value is default value.

When the element lose the focus, You could check, if it's empty, and if Yes - restore the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this as working, just make sure you put the `<script>` part just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<input type="text" class="input1" autofocus="focus" id="search" value="Type here..." onKeyPress="checkValue()" />

----

<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchEl = document.getElementById('search');
    var defaultValue = searchEl.value;

    function checkValue() {
        if (searchEl.value == defaultValue) {
            searchEl.value = "";
        }          
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cT9kg/11/ << I have updated the jsfiddle but it shows the text highlighted in blue. How can I have it so the line to start typing is at the front and when the text is deleted and clicked off of the value text appears again? like the 'Title' input on the 'Ask a Question' page

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Try it in a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/aliziv/2/edit. jsfiddle seems to have issues with my example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML `placeholder` attribute, but in the majority of browsers that won't achieve quite what you are after: as soon as the input is focused, the placeholder text disappears.

For functionality akin to iOS (found on sites such as Twitter as well), you need to use JavaScript. One example can be [seen online here](http://mrcoles.com/blog/persistent-placeholders-tutorial-focus/).

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630540/jquery-placeholder-that-shows-the-placeholder-until-text-is-typed/8127353#8127353) ([and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324767/javscript-plugin-to-manage-placeholder)) have some useful alternatives and code examples.

You're correctly using `autofocus`, which is fine but has patchy browser support. You can add in a JS fallback, like this ([taken from here](http://www.html5tuts.co.uk/demos/forms/)):

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
        document.getElementById("s").focus();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: See my edit above for a simple way to provide autofocus fallback. If you're going to be using numerous HTML5 features, you might want to look into using the excellent http://www.modernizr.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I tried digging around in the source code for the `Ask a question` page. Talk about convoluted.

Here is the [CSS File](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=6c0b7093abb5).
While it seems the relevant bits are thus, they don't seem to DO much more than format (other than the `edit-field-overlay` trick.

```
.form-item {padding:10px 0px 15px 0px;}
.ask-title            {margin-bottom:-15px;margin-top:-10px;}
.ask-title-table      {width:668px;}
.ask-title-field      {width:610px;}
.ask-title-cell-value {padding-left:5px;}
.edit-field-overlay   {display:none;}
```

HTML (some TD tags removed):

```
    <div class="form-item ask-title">
        <table class="ask-title-table">
            <tr>
                <td class="ask-title-cell-value">
                    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" class="ask-title-field" value="">                        
                    <span class="edit-field-overlay">what&#39;s your programming question? be specific.</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

But I totally could NOT figure out the relevant [Javascript bits.](http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=e922af98260a) As there are NO onEvent handlers for this form that I can see, the only reference to this field (`title`) would be in the `prepareEditor` function.

Anybody care to try and explain it to a relative newbie??