# Placeholder doesn't work on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html

You might think that this question is already answered.

However, I couldn't find the right code to make this happen for a week.

Jquery website doesn't support to users to download their placeholder file on the browser.

1. Placeholder should work on IE 7 and IE 8.
2. It will be great if I can use Jquery.
3. when a user clicks the input box, I hope it doesn't disappear until the user actually start to type a value.
4. It should work on password input too. (Password word box should show 'Password')

Can you help me out to figure out this problem?

It will be good for new users to find fresh answer.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630540/jquery-placeholder-that-shows-the-placeholder-until-text-is-typed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
 $(function() {

    if(!$.support.placeholder) { 

        var active = document.activeElement;

        $(':text').focus(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {

                $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');

            }

        }).blur(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {

                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');

            }

        });

        $(':text').blur();

        $(active).focus();

        $('form').submit(function () {

            $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });

        });

    }

});
```

In CSS add:

```
.hasPlaceholder {
    color: #777;
}
```

Comment: yeah I did, but it shows only ***** value. Is there a way to show 'Password' text?

Comment: You can try usign a background-image when is a :password type or initialize with a text input to change on blur for password.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the In-Field Labels jQuery Plugin

http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

I combined it with http://modernizr.com/ to check if placeholders are supported:

```
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
  $("input, textarea").inFieldLabels();
}
```

Comment: PS. I do believe in the principles of graceful degradation. Placeholders should shown where supported. Is hard to justify that to clients though.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following works perfectly to get placeholder function working in IE8:

This is the HTML:

```
<input id="user_userid" name="user_userid" placeholder="User-ID" type="text" value="" />
```

This is the Coffeescript code:

```
$(document).ready -> 

  if (document.all && !document.addEventListener) 
    $('input[placeholder]').each  ->     
      input = $(this) 
      input.closest('form').submit -> 
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) 
          input.val('')
```

The line "... document:addEventListener ..." checks for IE8 or earlier. With this code the placeholder handling happens when the containing form is submitted.

Best regards,

Christian 
http://www.agile-methoden.de